# Extending RelativeLayout, and overriding dispatchDraw() to create a zoomable ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-viewgroup

I've seen a few people ask how to zoom an entire ViewGroup (such as a RelativeLayout) in one go. At the moment this is something I need to achieve. The most obvious approach, to me, would be to hold the zoom scale factor as a single variable somewhere; and in each of the child Views' onDraw() methods, that scale factor would be applied to the Canvas prior to graphics being drawn.

However, before doing that, I have tried to be clever (ha - usually a bad idea) and extend RelativeLayout, into a class called ZoomableRelativeLayout. My idea is that any scale transformation could be applied just once to the Canvas in the overridden dispatchDraw() function, so that there would be absolutely no need to separately apply the zoom in any of the child views.

Here's what I did in my ZoomableRelativeLayout. It's just a simple extension of RelativeLayout, with dispatchDraw() being overridden:

```
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas){         
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);       
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);     
    canvas.restore();       
}
```

The mScaleFactor is manipulated by a ScaleListener in the same class.

It does actually work. I can pinch to zoom the ZoomableRelativeLayout, and all of the views held within properly rescale together.

Except there's a problem. Some of those child views are animated, and hence I periodically call invalidate() on them. When the scale is 1, those child views are seen to redraw periodically perfectly fine. When the scale is other than 1, those animated child views are only seen to update in a portion of their viewing area - or not at all - depending on the zoom scale.

My initial thinking was that when an individual child view's invalidate() is being called, then it's possibly being redrawn individually by the system, rather than being passed a Canvas from the parent RelativeLayout's dispatchDraw(), meaning that the child view ends up refreshing itself without the zoom scale applied. But oddly, the elements of the child views that are redrawn on the screen are to the correct zoom scale. It's almost as if the area that the system decides to actually update in the backing bitmap remains unscaled - if that makes sense. To put it another way, if I have a single animated child View and I gradually zoom in further and further from an initial scale of 1, and if we place an imaginary box on the area where that child view is when the zoom scale is 1, then the calls to invalidate() only cause a refresh of the graphics in that imaginary box. But the graphics that are seen to update *are* being done to the right scale. If you zoom in so far that the child view has now moved completely away from where it was with a scale of 1, then no part of it at all is seen to refresh. I'll give another example: imagine my child view is a ball that animates by switching between yellow and red. If I zoom in a little bit such that the ball moves to the right and down, at a certain point you'll just see the top-left quarter of the ball animate colours.

If I continuously zoom in and out, I see the child views animate properly and entirely. This is because the entire ViewGroup is being redrawn.

I hope this makes sense; I've tried to explain as best as I can. Am I on a bit of a loser with my zoomable ViewGroup strategy? Is there another way?

Thanks,

Trev

Comment: After lots of reading, I'm now under the impression that this is to do with the display area / 'invalid area' / clip area that is initially determined for a View. I have tried using android:clipChildren="false" but that had no effect.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the child views in the hierarchy viewer after zooming in?

Comment: To confirm your theory of the invalidated area, try installing the "Dev Tools" app (com.android.development, should already be installed in the emulator), open the app and go to "Development Settings" > check "Show screen updates".  That will cause any screen updates caused by invalidated areas to be highlighted in magenta.  As for your use case, I think it would be very strange to animate the views while it is scaled in any way.  Try overriding [canAnimate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#canAnimate%28%29) and return false if zoomed in?

Comment: Joe and matheeeny: Many thanks for these suggestions; it's much appreciated. I have in the meantime come to a working solution (which I have presented as an answer below) but I shall now have a go with the development tools that you mention, as it will be worthwhile experience.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are applying a scale factor to the drawing of your children, you also need to apply the appropriate scale factor to all of the other interactions with them -- dispatching touch events, invalidates, etc.

So in addition to dispatchDraw(), you will need to override and appropriate adjust the behavior of at least these other methods.  To take care of invalidates, you will need to override this method to adjust the child coordinates appropriately:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#invalidateChildInParent(int[], android.graphics.Rect)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#invalidateChildInParent%28int%5b%5d,%20android.graphics.Rect%29)

If you want the user to be able to interact with the child views you will also need to override this to adjust touch coordinates appropriately before they are dispatched to the children:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Also I would strongly recommend you implement this all inside of a simple ViewGroup subclass that has a single child view it manages.  This will get rid of any complexity of behavior that RelativeLayout is introducing in its own ViewGroup, simplifying what you need to deal with and debug in your own code.  Put the RelativeLayout as a child of your special zooming ViewGroup.

Finally, one improvement to your code -- in dispatchDraw() you want to save the canvas state *after* applying the scaling factor.  This ensures that the child can't modify the transformation you have set.

Comment: Hackbod : When will you be online. I need ur help for the same if you can help ...we can chat somewhere ? Thanks in advance

Comment: shouldn't setScaleX/Y do this for each of the children in the view group?

Answer (score 14):

The excellent answer from hackbod has reminded me that I need to post up the solution that I eventually came to. Please note that this solution, which worked for me for the application I was doing at the time, could be further improved with hackbod's suggestions. In particular I didn't need to handle touch events, and until reading hackbod's post it did not occur to me that if I did then I would need to scale those as well.

To recap, for my application I what I needed to achieve was to have a large diagram (specifically, the floor layout of a building) with other small "marker" symbols superimposed upon it. The background diagram and foreground symbols are all drawn using vector graphics (that is, Path() and Paint() objects applied to Canvas in the onDraw() method). The reason for wanting to create all the graphics this way, as opposed to just using bitmap resources, is because the graphics are converted at run-time using my SVG image converter.

The requirement was that the diagram and associated marker symbols would all be children of a ViewGroup, and could all be pinch-zoomed together.

A lot of the code looks messy (it was a rush job for a demonstration) so rather than just copying it all in, instead I'll try to just explain how I did it with the relevant bits of code quoted.

First of all, I have a ZoomableRelativeLayout.

```
public class ZoomableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout { ...
```

This class includes listener classes that extend ScaleGestureDetector and SimpleGestureListener so that the layout can be panned and zoomed. Of particular interest here is the scale gesture listener, which sets a scale factor variable and then calls invalidate() and requestLayout(). I'm not strictly certain at the moment if invalidate() is necessary, but anyway - here it is:

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector){
    mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
    // Apply limits to the zoom scale factor:
    mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.6f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 1.5f);
    invalidate();
    requestLayout();
    return true;
    }
}
```

The next thing I had to do in my ZoomableRelativeLayout was to override onLayout(). To do this I found it useful to look at other people's attempts at a zoomable layout, and also I found it very useful to look at the original Android source code for RelativeLayout. My overridden method copies much of what's in RelativeLayout's onLayout() but with some modifications.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    int count = getChildCount();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        View child = getChildAt(i); 
        if(child.getVisibility()!=GONE){
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();
            child.layout(
                (int)(params.leftMargin * mScaleFactor), 
                (int)(params.topMargin * mScaleFactor), 
                (int)((params.leftMargin + child.getMeasuredWidth()) * mScaleFactor), 
                (int)((params.topMargin + child.getMeasuredHeight()) * mScaleFactor) 
                );
        }
    }
}
```

What's significant here is that when calling 'layout()' on all the children, I'm applying the scale factor to the layout parameters as well for those children. This is one step towards solving the clipping problem, and also it importantly correctly sets the x,y position of the children relative to each other for different scale factors.

A further key thing is that I am no longer attempting to scale the Canvas in dispatchDraw(). Instead each child View scales its Canvas after obtaining the scale factor from the parent ZoomableRelativeLayout via a getter method.

Next, I shall move onto what I had to do within the child Views of my ZoomableRelativeLayout. There's only one type of View I contain as children in my ZoomableRelativeLayout; it's a View for drawing SVG graphics that I call SVGView. Of course the SVG stuff is not relevant here. Here's its onMeasure() method:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {


    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    float parentScale = ((FloorPlanLayout)getParent()).getScaleFactor();
    int chosenWidth, chosenHeight;
    if( parentScale > 1.0f){
        chosenWidth =  (int) ( parentScale * (float)svgImage.getDocumentWidth() );
        chosenHeight = (int) ( parentScale * (float)svgImage.getDocumentHeight() );
    }
    else{
        chosenWidth =  (int) (  (float)svgImage.getDocumentWidth() );
        chosenHeight = (int) (  (float)svgImage.getDocumentHeight() );          
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);
}
```

And the onDraw():

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){   
    canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);       

    canvas.scale(((FloorPlanLayout)getParent()).getScaleFactor(), 
            ((FloorPlanLayout)getParent()).getScaleFactor());       


    if( null==bm  ||  bm.isRecycled() ){
        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                getMeasuredWidth(),
                getMeasuredHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


        ... Canvas draw operations go here ...
    }       

    Paint drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);

    // Check again that bm isn't null, because sometimes we seem to get
    // android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled exception sometimes even though bitmap should
    // have been drawn above. I'm guessing at the moment that this *might* happen when zooming into
    // the house layout quite far and the system decides not to draw anything to the bitmap because
    // a particular child View is out of viewing / clipping bounds - not sure. 
    if( bm != null){
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0f, 0f, drawPaint );
    }

    canvas.restore();

}
```

Again - as a disclaimer, there are probably some warts in what I have posted there and I am yet to carefully go through hackbod's suggestions and incorporate them. I intend to come back and edit this further. In the meantime, I hope it can start to provide useful pointers to others on how to implement a zoomable ViewGroup.

Comment: what is the FloorPlanLayout? can you then give whole code or a example,when i use your code but not run though you Explained very detailed.

Comment: WHat is the floor plan layout ? I also did not understood. I have made custom RelativeLayout by reading on your link. My custom relative layout behaves as a parent layout for my 7 Image views. Now problems faced are ? 1. If i keep the image as background of relativeLayout and i try to zoom it does not get zoom but if i make it as an Imageview and place it as child of custom RelativeLayout it gets zoom properly with the many imageViews inside WHy custom relative layout does not zoom the background set to it ??

Comment: For anyone that stumbles onto this (or gets linked here), the FloorPlanLayout is irrelevant. It is more or less the root view container where the scale is initially set, with the view documented being an intermediate view that holds the content.