# Scaling image of ImageView while maintaining center point in same place

Tags: android, android-image, android-imageview

I have set a prescaled Bitmap as ImageView's source. Then I've read Matrix of an `ImageView` and shift Bitmap of an ImageView via `matrix.postTranslate(shiftX, shiftY)`.

Now I want to zoom in / out and image while maintaining center of `ImageView` at the same point of Bitmap that was before scale.

If I try to zoom in an image with `matrix.postScale(zoom, zoom)`, point that I want to maintain (blue dot) shifts to other place (purple dot).

I have tried several different ways to shift Bitmap back, but I cant get it to work correctly. I know initial Bitmap size, ImageView size, distances marked by doted line. Tried to calculate needed shift and use `matrix.postTranslate(-zoomshiftX, -zoomshiftY)` afterwards, but it doesn't shift correctly.

Even found out, that underlying Bitmap's pixel count doesnt change after  matrix.postScale() function and tried matrix.postTranslate(-zoomshiftX/zoom, -zoomshiftY/zoom) - but still no luck.

How do I achieve such zoom?

[image: scalling issue]

Comment: I have achieved centered zooming by using 4 argument matrix.postScale() and entering something like View_width/2 and View_height/2 for last two arguments. Didnt realize that these last two arguments might refer to View's pixels, not that of the Bitmap

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my question here regarding creating a zoomable ViewGroup. I've described code snippets from my end solution, and some of it might be helpful.

[Extending RelativeLayout, and overriding dispatchDraw() to create a zoomable ViewGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378904/extending-relativelayout-and-overriding-dispatchdraw-to-create-a-zoomable-view/6490515#6490515)

Comment: Both that question and answers are both of my league :/ I dont use any canvas'es nor overiding any scaling methods.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be helpful:

If you got two fingers on screen, you can get the event of the two fingers and get the mid point:

```
PointF mid;
MotionEvent event;
float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
mid.set(x / 2, y / 2);
```

Then you can set the scalation having the mid point in the center of the screen:

```
matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
```