# Canvas Pinch-Zoom to Point Within Bounds

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-gesture

I've been stuck on this problem for eight hours, so I figured it was time to get some help.

Before I begin my problem, I'll just let it be known that I've been through this site and Google, and none of the answers I've found have helped. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848523/canvas-zoom-goes-to-point-0-0) is one, [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835224/android-bitmap-canvas-offset-after-scale), and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624103/scaling-image-of-imageview-while-maintaining-center-point-in-same-place).)

Here's the deal: I have a class that extends `SurfaceView` (let's call it `MySurface`) and overrides many methods in it. Normally, it draws several squares and text boxes, which is all fine. As soon as a user starts touching, it converts to a `Bitmap`, then draws each frame that until the user releases.

Here's the rub: I want to implement such a functionality that the user can place two fingers on the screen, pinch to zoom, and also pan around (but ONLY with two fingers down).

I found a few implementations of pinch-to-zoom and adapted them to my `Canvas` object in `MySurface` via the following:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();

    canvas.scale(mScaleVector.z, mScaleVector.z); // This is the scale factor as seen below
    canvas.translate(mScaleVector.x, mScaleVector.y); // These are offset values from 0,0, both working fine

    // Start draw code

    // ...

    // End draw code

    canvas.restore();
}
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float factor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        if (Math.abs(factor - 1.0f) >= 0.0075f) {
            mScaleVector.z *= factor;
            mScaleVector.z = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(mScaleVector.z, MAX_ZOOM));
        }

        // ...

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }
}
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
    if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN && pointerIndex == 1) {
            // The various pivot coordinate codes would belong here
        }
    }

    detector.onTouchEvent(event); // Calls the Scale Gesture Detector
    return true;
}
```

While both elements work fine--the scrolling back and forth and the pinch-to-zoom--there is one large problem. The pinch-to-zoom, when used, zooms into the point `0,0`, instead of zooming into the finger point.

I've tried a lot of ways to fix this:

- Using `canvas.scale(mScaleVector.z, mScaleVector.z, mScaleVector.x, mScaleVector.y);`; obviously, this produces unwanted results as the `mScaleVector` x and y values are 0-offsets.
- Managing a "pivot" coordinate that uses the same offset as the `translate()` method, but this produces either the same `0,0` issue, or jumping around when the view is touched.
- Numerous other things... I've done a lot with the aforementioned pivot coordinate, trying to base its location on the user's first touch, and moving it relative to that touch each successive gesture.

Additionally, this canvas must be bounded, so the user cannot scroll forever. However, when I use the `.scale(sx, sy, px, py)` method, it pushes things beyond any bounds I set in `.translate()`.

I'm... pretty much open to anything at this point. I know this functionality can be added, as it is seen in the Android 4.0 gallery (when viewing a single image). I've tried to track down the source code that handles this, to no avail.

Comment: I personally handle the two finger positions directly using the `onTouchEvent`. With this, you can easily find the mid point, and how much scaling is required.

Comment: can you please post the solution if you have solved the issue I am facing same problem, and my client is.... :(, or can you tell me how you have solve the problem. thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the code I use to implement pinch zoom in an `ImageView` using `ScaleGestureDetector`. With little or no modification you should be able to use it too, since you can use transformation marices too, to draw on a `Canvas`.

```
@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    float mScaleFactor = (float) Math.min(
        Math.max(.8f, detector.getScaleFactor()), 1.2);
    float origScale = saveScale;
    saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
    if (saveScale > maxScale) {
        saveScale = maxScale;
        mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
    } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
        saveScale = minScale;
        mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
    }
    right = width * saveScale - width
            - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
    bottom = height * saveScale - height
            - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
    if (origWidth * saveScale <= width
            || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {
        matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
        if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) {
                    if (y < -bottom)
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                    else if (y > 0)
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                } else {
                    if (x < -right)
                        matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                    else if (x > 0)
                        matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
        matrix.getValues(m);
        float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
        if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
            if (x < -right)
                matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
            else if (x > 0)
                matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
            if (y < -bottom)
                matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
            else if (y > 0)
                matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In my case, I computed the neccesary values in the `onMeasure()` method of the View, you might want to do this somewhere else in your `SurfaceView`

```
width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec); // Change this according to your screen size
height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec); // Change this according to your screen size

// Fit to screen.
float scale;
float scaleX = (float) width / (float) bmWidth;
float scaleY = (float) height / (float) bmHeight;
scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
setImageMatrix(matrix);
saveScale = 1f;
scaleMappingRatio = saveScale / scale;

// Center the image
redundantYSpace = (float) height - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
redundantXSpace = (float) width - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

A little explanation:

`saveScale` is the current scale ratio of the `Bitmap`

`mScaleFactor` is the factor you have to multiply your scale ratio with.

`maxScale` and `minScale` can be constant values.

`width` and `height` are the dimensions of the screen.

`redundantXSpace` and `redundantYSpace` are the empty between the image borders and screen borders since the image is centered when in it is smaller then the screen

`origHeight` and `origWidth` are the sizes of the bitmap

`matrix` is the current transformation matrix used to draw the bitmap

The trick is, that when I first scaled and centered the image on initialization, I picked that scale ratio to be 1 and with `scaleMappingRatio` I mapped the actual scale values of the image relative to that.

Comment: Oh man, after reviewing and thoroughly testing aspects of your code, I discovered those matrix transformations were the key! I'd buy you a beer if I could! A+, good sir.

Comment: You are welcome, I spent a lot of time figuring out the right way too, when I started writing the code above, I thought it would worth sharing.

Answer (score -1):

```
    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.Save();

        int x = (int)(canvas.Width * mScaleFactor - canvas.Width) / 2;
        int y = (int)(canvas.Height * mScaleFactor - canvas.Height) / 2;

        if (mPosX > (canvas.Width + x - 50))
        {
            mPosX = canvas.Width + x - 50;
        }
        if (mPosX < (50 - canvas.Width - x))
        {
            mPosX = 50 - canvas.Width - x;
        }
        if (mPosY > (canvas.Height + y - 50))
        {
            mPosY = canvas.Height + y - 50;
        }
        if (mPosY < (50 - canvas.Height - y))
        {
            mPosY = 50 - canvas.Height - y;
        }

        canvas.Translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.Scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, canvas.Width/2, canvas.Height/2);
        base.OnDraw(canvas);
        canvas.Restore();
    }
```

This is monodroid code, but can be easily converted to JAVA.
You may choose whatever values for your bound (here is 50 pixels margin)

Comment: Here is a library that wil do this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578320/how-to-apply-zoom-drag-and-rotation-to-an-image-in-android/47861501#47861501