# Custom Viewgroup that can handle Zoom and Scroll

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, viewgroup

I want to make custom Relative Layout which can handle Zoom and Scroll both. Any good example where i can learn about the Custom RelativeLayout which does the same or little.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: may be this link be useful for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378904/extending-relativelayout-and-overriding-dispatchdraw-to-create-a-zoomable-vie