# Zooming a layout (Relative Layout) in android

Tags: android, android-layout, pinchzoom, zooming

I want to zoom in and out all the images inside the layout. I have seen many questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013906/android-zoom-in-out-relativelayout-with-spread-pinch) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378904/extending-relativelayout-and-overriding-dispatchdraw-to-create-a-zoomable-vie?lq=1)  and tried to implement them but I couldn't.

Please help me in order to understand this. My confusion is, why would I extend my class from relative layout, as described in the question above, i mean i have a relative layout in my XML and I am setting this XML in content view but how could I grab the specific relative layout by using this methodology. And even if I have extended class from relative layout, how would I use this class in the activity which contains my images inside layout.

My XML setup is like this, can anyone please tell me what approach I have to follow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.cpec.farrukhtanveer.MainActivity">

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="130dp"
       android:background="@drawable/imageBackGround">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/img_one"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          android:src="@drawable/imageone"/>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/img_two"
          android:visibility="invisible"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="imagetwo"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help folks ! 
Thanks.
Umair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one came up with solution, I kind of sort it out myself and thought it might be helpful for some one else who is stuck in this problem. The basic guidance came from [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html), where author implemented the zoom in and out for a single image, we just have to add images and handle other initialization as described in that tutorial.

**ImageViewWithZoomClass:**

```
private Drawable imageOne, imageTwo;
imageOne = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon1); 
imageTwo = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon2);
.
.
imageOne.setBounds(0, 0, imageOne.getIntrinsicWidth(), imageOne.getIntrinsicHeight());
imageTwo.setBounds(0, 0, imageTwo.getIntrinsicWidth(), imageTwo.getIntrinsicHeight());
.
.
imageOne.draw(canvas);
imageTwo.draw(canvas);
```

and since I am using relative layout, I just used onClickListener in my **MainActivity** like this

```
relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(new ImageViewWithZoom(getApplicationContext()));
        }
    });
```

and XML for the relative layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="130dp"
    android:background="@drawable/abc"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/roadandrailways"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/capital"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can add multiple images in layout.
Thats it, hope it helps.